# Swift AwaitKit with Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, promise, async-await

I'm trying to implement firebase database with swifts `AwaitKit`, which delivers await/async and uses swifts `PromiseKit` under hood. The problem is that when I put firebase code inside promise it always fails on `NSURLSession` with this error

> "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)"

However http call it self uses https not http. I tried to allow `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, `NSExceptionDomains` nothings helps me. Here is code.

```
let data: [String: Any] = [
        "test": 1,
        "test2": "user"
    ]

    let promise: Promise<Bool> = Promise { resolve, reject in
        ref.child("test/picks").setValue(data) { err, _ in
            if err == nil {
                resolve(true)
            } else {
                reject(err!)
            }
        }
    }

    let isStored = try! await(promise)
```

Comment: Please share sample project if possible

Comment: @Hiteshsurani Here is link to bitbucket repo  https://bitbucket.org/vadim_krutov/firebase-test, please make sure that you upload your GoogleService-Info.plist file and enter credentials in AppDelegate.swift file

Comment: okay i will do and revert if found any solution

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, here a working snippet with Xcode 11 Beta 5, SwiftUI, AwaitKit, PromiseKit and Firestore.

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase
import PromiseKit
import AwaitKit


final class UserStore: ObservableObject {
    let collection: CollectionReference

    init() {
        collection = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
    }


    func create(userId: String, familyName: String, givenName: String, email: String) {
         async {
            let fetchUser : Promise<String> = Promise { seal in
                self.collection.document("HFlTjPHgbXH96q6LQ93N").getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let document = document, document.exists {
                        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                        seal.fulfill(dataDescription)
                    } else {
                        seal.reject(NSError())
                    }
                }
            }
            let user = try! await(fetchUser)
            print("My user:", user)
        }
    }
}
```