# Firebase calls with PromiseKit/AwaitKit in Swift never returns

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous, promisekit

Similarly to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46925702/5569234), I have been unable to use Firebase Auth and Database calls with a [Promise](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) in Swift. I am able use such calls in a completion handler like this (as long as the completion handler isn't within a Promise):

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: "/Path/To/My/Data").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (result) in
    // do things with the result
})
```

But not like this (I am using [AwaitKit](https://github.com/yannickl/AwaitKit) to wait for the promise to finish):

```
func getData(from path: String) -> Promise<DataSnapshot> {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: path)

    return Promise { (fulfill, reject) in
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (result) in
            fulfill(result) // this is never called
        })
    }
}

await(getData(from: "/Path/To/My/Data")) // this never completes
```

When I call `await(getData(from: "/Path/To/My/Data"))`, the call never completes and the rest of the code after the call never executes. The same issue occurs when trying to authenticate using the `Auth.auth().signInAnonymously(completion:)` method; it works perfectly fine by itself but never returns when inside a promise. After running for about a minute, both calls automatically terminate with the following message in the console:

> TIC TCP Conn Failed [6:0x12190e8b0]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)

I'm thinking that the issue may lie in the fact that AwaitKit uses semaphores to wait for the promise to fulfill, but I'm not entirely sure.

So how can I successfully use Firebase from within a promise? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where's your `async` that's suppose to go along with your `await`?

Comment: Ah, that's what I missed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `async` around the `await` call fixed my issue, like so:

```
async {
    await(getData(from: "/Path/To/My/Data"))
    // continue execution
}
```

Comment: If you don't know why.. it's because `await` is a blocking call and calling it on the `mainQueue` will block the main thread indefinitely.. If the promise is executed on the `mainQueue` as well, then it will never complete because the `mainQueue` is already blocked by a call to `await`..